# Changing frequency is a linear transformation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, eigenfunctions

Does changing the frequency of sinusoidal curves count as linear transformation? Im studying about eigen values and functions in PDE. There it sin (lambda.x) is a eigen function with eigen value lambda.

Comment: it is an eigenfunction of which transormation? And what does it mean for you "change the frequency"?

Comment: Sin(lambda x) in this lambda xhanges tbe frequency of the sin curve. My doubt is whether changing the frequency is a linear transformation?

Comment: the problem is, to prove that a transformation is linear, you have to define the domain and codomain. In other words, your frequency change brings what to what?

Comment: Sorry i can't get u